# Java PreparedStatement retrieving last inserted ID

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, prepared-statement

This answer to this question done this way seems to be very difficult to find on the internet. Basically I am inserting values into a MySQL database using PreparedStatement. I use the PreparedStatement to escape the data to prevent SQL Injection attacks. The problem is, there is now way retreving those keys.

```
String query="Insert INTO Table_A(name, age) (?, ?)";
//String query="Insert INTO Table_A(name, age) ('abc','123' )";//Doesn't escape
PreparedStatement prest;
prest = con.prepareStatement(query);
prest.setString(1,"abc");
prest.setInt(2,123);
prest.executeUpdate();
//prest.executeUpdate(query, PreparedStatement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS); Throws an error
//prest.executeQuery(); Throws an error
```

So how can I escape input and use PreparedStatements in Java?

Comment: Pass the `RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS` to the `prepareStatement()` call and use `executeUpdate()` to exeute the insert. If that doesn't work, please provide the exception.

Comment: @BalusC references a correct method of doing this.

Comment: @BalusC, that is exactly what I was looking for. To bad its not an answer!

Comment: I've just voted for close as duplicate.

Answer (score 75):

pass `Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS` in `prepareStatement()` along with your query. And then use getGeneratedKeys() of `PreparedStatement` to get the ResultSet containing your inserted auto_incremented_id.

```
String query="Insert INTO Table_A(name, age) (?, ?)";
                //String query="Insert INTO Table_A(name, age) ('abc','123' )";//Doesn't escape
                PreparedStatement prest;
                prest = con.prepareStatement(query, Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);
                prest.setString(1,"abc");
                prest.setInt(2,123);
                prest.executeUpdate();
                //prest.executeUpdate(query, PreparedStatement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS); Throws an error
                //prest.executeQuery(); Throws an error
                ResultSet rs = prest.getGeneratedKeys();
                if(rs.next())
                {
                    int last_inserted_id = rs.getInt(1);
                }
```

Comment: i want to add this query before my insert statement to allow emojis in my table -> SET NAMES utf8mb4; but now i am unable to get last insert id from my insert query in prepared statement. what should i do

Answer (score 4):

Use 
[java.sql.ResultSet java.sql.Statement.getGeneratedKeys()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#getGeneratedKeys%28%29) to retrieve your generated keys.

Answer (score 0):

If you can't use `RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS`, use another statement (a query this time) to do

```
SELECT last_insert_id()
```

Make sure that you definitely have an auto-increment primary key column in that table.

Comment: Does this also work for the situation that there were multiple inserts to the same table that you're trying to get id for one of the inserts?