# Mysql 2 insert queries

Tags: mysql, jdbc

I am trying to execute 2 queries.

First one should insert data (especially "product") or update in case the db already has a row with such title.

Second one should insert new category for product which was inserted\updated from 1st query and ignore any inserts, if table already has such product with such category

Here is my code :

```
 conn = DatabaseConnection.getConnection();
 stmt = conn.createStatement();
 conn.setAutoCommit(false);

 String updateSQL = "INSERT INTO product (title, price, `status`) " +
                "VALUES(?, ?, ?)" +
                "ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE price = ?, `status` = ?;"

 PreparedStatement preparedStatement = conn.prepareStatement(updateSQL);
 preparedStatement.setString(1, product.getTitle());
 preparedStatement.setBigDecimal(2, product.getPrice());
 preparedStatement.setInt(3, product.getStatus().ordinal());
 preparedStatement.executeUpdate();

 updateSQL = "INSERT IGNORE INTO product_categories (product_id, category_id) " +
             "VALUES (last_insert_id(), ?);";
 preparedStatement = conn.prepareStatement(updateSQL);
 preparedStatement.setLong(1, categoryId);
 preparedStatement.executeUpdate();
 conn.commit();
```

So, the problem is that I use `last_insert_id()` which means that i will use incorrect row in 2nd query if 1st query just updated the data.

So, I would like to know how could I synchronize these 2 queries.

Comment: yeap, i just forgot to copy that.
I can't clearly understand, what is "fetch"
"[See this question for details]" is just a string, it's not a link

Comment: (Sorry - forgot to paste the link) Fetch the last_insert_id from your first query, and only execute the second query if it exists. [See this question for details](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5513180/java-preparedstatement-retrieving-last-inserted-id)

Comment: could you provide an example please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you don't have access to `last_insert_id()` in the second query, you'll have to fetch it [as in the answers for this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5513180/java-preparedstatement-retrieving-last-inserted-id).

Here's an example:

```
...
preparedStatement.executeUpdate();    // this is the first query

ResultSet rs = preparedStatement.getGeneratedKeys();
if ( rs.next() )
{
    long last_insert_id = rs.getLong(1);

    updateSQL = "INSERT IGNORE INTO product_categories (product_id, category_id) " +
            "VALUES (?, ?);";
    preparedStatement = conn.prepareStatement(updateSQL);
    preparedStatement.setLong(1, last_insert_id);
    preparedStatement.setLong(2, categoryId);
    preparedStatement.executeUpdate();
}
conn.commit();
```

If the first query didn't result in an INSERT, then there isn't enough information to add the product to the product_category, in which case this is skipped all together. This does assume that the product is already in the category. If you're not sure about that, and want to execute the second query regardless, you could query for the product_id:

```
SELECT id FROM product WHERE title = ?
```

and then use that `id` instead of the `last_insert_id` variable, or, you could change the second query and use `title` as a key (although I'd stick with an `id`):

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO product_categories (product_id, category_id) 
VALUES (SELECT id FROM product WHERE title = ?), ?)
```